# Comments in .java change ByteCode of .class file

Tags: java, bytecode

My understanding is that the Java compiler does not include comments in bytecode in the output .class file.

However I have the code:

```
InputStream stream = getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
byte[] classBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
```

I run it for my java class, add a comment to the java code, and re-run it. I see that classBytes is different just from the added comment

Comment: Byte code includes line numbers, so that stack trace can be constructed. Comments may change the line number on which a particular statement appears.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Java compiler does not include bytecode in the output .class file"? the .class file IS the bytecode.

Comment: editted* - meant "does not include comments in the bytecode in the compile .class file"

Comment: You can compile with `javac -g:none` and check the class file.

Comment: Comments are included in the class-file. Try it yourself. Compile a class of yours and the have a look in it using a decompiler.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not included in the classfile. However, the compiler does by default include some metadata for debugging purposes, which includes line numbers. If your comments span a line or more, that will obviously change the line numbers of everything, and hence the resulting classfile will change.

You can pass `-g:none` to `javac` to avoid including line numbers and other optional metadata.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranty that the same source code produces exactly the same byte code. The standard does not mandate how certain language constructs are mapped to byte code constructs and certain “best practices” have changed over time or differ between compiler implementations. Some aspects, e.g. the order of the methods within a class file are considered entirely irrelevant and may be the result of some implementation specific aspects of the compiler instead of a deliberate decision.

Usually, using exactly the same compiler implementation and version will reproduce the same byte code, as the compiler’s program code is deterministic, but that doesn’t have to be, e.g. some hash map implementations have a randomization feature, also compilers might utilize parallel pro­cess­ing which may add indeterminism to aspects considered irrelevant to the result.

Given that even exactly the same source code is not guaranteed to produce identical bytecode, it should not surprise that even small, actually irrelevant changes may cause differences in the bytecode, as even if nothing else changes they may have an impact on timing or hash codes.

As said by others, inserting a comment line may change the line numbers in debug attributes which are included by default, so that’s a simple reason to get different byte code. But it is important to understand that your assumption to always get identical byte code is fundamentally flawed.

Note that a similar wrong assumption has already led to a major design flaw in the Java API. The default `serialVersionUID` is calculated by hashing class data which are actually irrelevant to the compatibility of serialized data. As [the documentation of `Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) states:

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is *strongly recommended* that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary de­pend­ing on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization.

Don’t repeat this mistake.

Comment: While true, I would be very surprised if using a fixed version of `javac` with all else being equal, inserting comments caused any changes other than line number changes. Compilers typically strip out comments at the first stage of parsing, so it is unlikely to affect the AST or subsequent steps.

At any rate, Google's version of javac is deterministic and reproducible, although I don't know how much they had to modify it to ensure that.

Comment: @Antimony what “Google's version of javac” are you talking about? I tried to search it, but all I could find, are identical copies of the javac repository, no special versions, not to speak of any official statement that reproducing byte for byte identical class files is a goal. Is there any reference for that? Besides that, comments are not entirely ignored. Just think `/** @deprecated */`…

Comment: Google's build system (Blaze/Bazel) relies on all build steps being deterministic. IIRC, they had to modify javac to make it determinstic, although that may have just been a matter of stripping the timestamps out of the jars produced.